# react-router match does not work after transpiling es6 with babel

Tags: reactjs, react-router

When running babel-node server.js everything works fine, but when I create a build and transpile my es6 code with babel the match function doesn't find a match and I always get returned the 404 error message. I am using this on my Isomorphic / Universal server.

When I console.log the values in the ES6 version and the transpiled version those are looking the same.

Actual ES6 match code in my server.js

```
let history = useRouterHistory(useQueries(createMemoryHistory))()
    let routes = createRoutes(history)
    let location = history.createLocation(req.url)

    match({ all_routes, location }, (error, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
        if (redirectLocation) {
            res.redirect(301, redirectLocation.pathname + redirectLocation.search)
        } else if (error) {
            res.status(500).send(error.message)
        } else if (renderProps == null) {
            res.status(404).send('Not found')
        } else {
```

My .babelrc looks like this:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", 'stage-2',"react"],
  "plugins": [ "transform-object-rest-spread","transform-react-jsx"]
}
```

My routes file:

```
const routes = function(){
    return (
        <Router history={browserHistory}>
            <Route path="/" component={App}>
                <IndexRoute component={Home} />
                <Route path="contact"   component={Contact} />
                <Route path="login"     component={Login} /> 
                <Route path="*"         component={NotFound} />
            </Route>
        </Router>
    )
}
```

When I console.log Routes it looks like this:

```
{ '$$typeof': Symbol(react.element),
  type: 
   { [Function]
     displayName: 'Route',
     createRouteFromReactElement: [Function: createRouteFromReactElement],
     propTypes: 
      { path: [Object],
        component: [Object],
        components: [Object],
        getComponent: [Object],
        getComponents: [Object] } },
  key: null,
  ref: null,
  props: 
   { path: '/',
     component: { [Function] displayName: 'App' },
     children: 
      [ [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object] ] },
  _owner: null,
  _store: {} }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`createRoutes` expects a `routes` object, but you are passing it a `history` instance. You will need to extract your `<Route>`s out of your `routes` function in a way that allows you to import them on the server.

```
// routes.js
export const routes = (
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    <IndexRoute component={Home} />
    <Route path="contact"   component={Contact} />
    <Route path="login"     component={Login} /> 
    <Route path="*"         component={NotFound} />
  </Route>
)
```

Then you would define your router as:

```
import { routes } from './routes'

function router() {
  return (
    <Router history={browserHistor}>
      {routes}
    </Router>
  )
}
```

And on the server, you would import the routes and you can pass them to `createRoutes` (although `match` will do this for you if you don't).

```
import { routes } from './routes'

function handler(req, res) {
  match({ routes, req.url }), function(...) {
    // ...
  })
}
```

Comment: So when I simplify the code to be like as you suggested, the problem still exists, in my dev environment it was previously working fine but after this update it does not. I added a console log of my Routes to the original post, it looks very similar as before my changes my req.url is a / as you can see is existing in the console log as well

Comment: That log is the routes from `let routes = createRoutes(history)`?

Comment: No this is just from console.log(routes) i got rid of the history for now (routes as in: import { routes } from './routes')

Comment: Urgh so stupid because of experimentation I changed `match({ routes, location },` to `match({ all_routes, location },` which of course sets the object keyword wrong and `routes` will be undefined. Also got it working with my previous setup.